# Converting input to lower case to accept in a while loop

Tags: python, input, case-sensitive, lowercase

I am trying to create a program that takes an input and will convert whatever input for example Yes / YES to lower case to be accepted in the while loop below. Ive tried to do it but doesnt work. Any idea?

```
#Import the random function - This only needs to be imported once.
import random

#Use a while loop to allow the user to repeat the process 
repeat = "YES"

while repeat == "yes":

#User is able to input which sided dice they want to throw.    
    dice = input("What side dice do you want to use? 4, 6, or 12?\n")
#4 sided
    if dice == "4":
        #Outputs what sided dice has been chosen and the score thay they rolled.
        print(dice, "sided dice chose.\nYou rolled a", random.randint(1,4))
#6 sided
    elif dice == "6":
        print(dice, "sided dice chose.\nYou rolled a", (random.randint(1,6)))
#12 sided
    elif dice == "12":
        print(dice, "sided dice chose.\nYou rolled a", (random.randint(1,12)))
#Incorrect value entered
    else:
        #Informs the user that the number they have chosen is not a valid option.
        print(dice, "is not a valid choice")
#Asks user if they want to use the program again.
    print("Do you want to use the program again? Yes or No?")
    #Links back to the start of the while loop.
    repeat = input()
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem that your initial value of repeat is upper case ;)

Comment: What did you try? Your attempt at lowercasing isn't visible in your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never even enter the `while` loop, as you set repeat to "YES" and then immediately check if it is "yes", which it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would have solved this in another way

```
while True:
    dice = input(....)
    #etc
    repeat = ''
    while repeat.lower() not in ['yes', 'no']:
        repeat = input('Do you want to use the program again? (yes/no)?')
    if repeat.lower() == 'no':
        break
```

This would ask the user to input yes or no, and keep on asking until yes or no in supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel is entirely correct. The `'YES'` at the beginning of the code should be formatted as `'yes'` because clearly `'YES` does not equal `'yes'` and thus the `while` loop won't run at all